Selecting only the statement with the minimum date qualifier
I'm trying to write a query telling me the age upon which heads of state first took office. I'm having trouble isolating the position held statement with the earliest start time qualifier. I can't seem to put MIN() in the right place.
Here's a query returning all of the ages upon taking office (with more than one entry for those taking office more than once):
SELECT ?headOfState ?headOfStateLabel ?age ?countryLabel ?positionLabel 
{
 # find heads of state positions
 hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
 ?position wdt:P279* wd:Q48352 .

 # sovereign states only
 ?position wdt:P1001 ?country .
 ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078 .
  
 # fetch names of officeholders
 ?headOfState wdt:P39 ?position .

 # birthdates of officeholders
 ?headOfState wdt:P569 ?dob. hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true. 
  
 # date of term start
 ?headOfState p:P39 ?statement .
 ?statement ps:P39 ?position . 
 ?statement pq:P580 ?termStart. hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true.
 FILTER("1950-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?termStart && ?termStart < "1980-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)
 BIND(YEAR(?termStart)-YEAR(?dob) as ?age)
 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?age)

link to wdqs
Earlier, before this update to my question, I was using SELECT DISTINCT and misplacing MIN() like so: BIND(MIN(YEAR(?termStart))-YEAR(?dob) as ?age), producing odd errors: it returns Anwar Sadat becoming president of Egypt at age 32. Sadat's date of birth is 1918, and there is no position held with a start time of 1950. So where does the number 32 come from?
Now, thanks to help I received, I have the right ages, but how do I select only the minimum age?
If, in the first line, I SELECT (MIN(?age) as ?ageMin), I get a bad aggregate (which makes sense I guess, because there are multiple entries for each head of state and this doesn't pick the single correct entry).
I've tried subqueries like
  {SELECT (MIN(?termStart) as ?termStartMin) WHERE {
 ?headOfState p:P39 ?statement .
 ?statement ps:P39 ?position . 
 ?statement pq:P580 ?termStart. hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true.
 FILTER("1950-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?termStart && ?termStart < "1980-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)}}
 BIND(YEAR(?termStartMin)-YEAR(?dob) as ?age)

but these are giving me crazy results.

MIN is an aggregate function in SPARQL, you can't use that in a BIND statement. You have to get the earliest position in a subquery.

you're getting weird result because there must be some bug. When select ?termstart you can see it's the correct statement with 1970, but when you also BIND min(year) it a separate variable and select this, it does show random years starting from 1950 - don't know what the query engine does there, nor what their semantics of an aggregate in a BIND expression is. but that's where the 32 comes from. 1950 - 1918

After moving MIN() from the body of the query to SELECT (thanks to the answer and comments I received), I had to sort out my aggregates. This discussion of bad aggregates helped, and the query now does what I want it to do:
# Age of heads of state upon taking power, 1950-1980
SELECT DISTINCT ?headOfState ?headOfStateLabel (MIN(?age) as ?ageMin) ?countryLabel ?positionLabel
{
 # find heads of state positions
 hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
 ?position wdt:P279* wd:Q48352 .

 # sovereign states only
 ?position wdt:P1001 ?country .
 ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078 .
  
 # fetch names of officeholders
 ?headOfState wdt:P39 ?position .

 # birthdates of officeholders
 ?headOfState wdt:P569 ?dob. hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true. 
  
 # date of term start
 ?headOfState p:P39 ?statement .
 ?statement ps:P39 ?position . 
 ?statement pq:P580 ?termStart. hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true.
  
 # 1950-1980 term start only
 FILTER("1950-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?termStart && ?termStart < "1980-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)
 
 # calcuate age 
 BIND(YEAR(?termStart)-YEAR(?dob) as ?age)
 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
GROUP BY ?headOfState ?headOfStateLabel ?countryLabel ?positionLabel
ORDER BY DESC(?ageMin)

try it

I was looking at your issue and, curiously, the query returns different values for ?age when also ?termStart and ?dob are added to the SELECT statement.
Anyway, the problem is that you are using MIN() in the body of the query.
